# How to switch PayPal sandbox account to live account in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi guys hope you are all safe. i just want to know that how can i switch sandbox account to live account.
First i was using `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` in paypal form action but when i go to live i changed it into `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`
i also changed the business attribute in form to Paypal live business account.
right now PayPal is accepting the payment which is coming from website but when it redirects to my website paypal_success(page after payment success) page i cant able to get return values from Paypal like transaction id, item value, item name etc.
Can you please help me. here is my code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" class="float-right w_100">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@awakeningsme.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Awakenings Products">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $pro_id ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mywebsite.com/paypal_success.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://mywebsite.com/paypal_cancel.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">

            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/buy-logo-large.png" alt="Buy now with PayPal" border="0" name="submit">

          </form>
```

Comment: You may have to enable [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/) in your PayPal business account. See section **Activating PDT**

Answer (score 1):

A more important issue is that PDT should never be used for anything important. It is for informational purposes only (e.g. to show a success page to the buyer)

If you depend on the information from PDT to trigger business logic like updating order records, you are going to have a bad time. After a successful Payments Standard payment, **the customer may never return**.

Their browser may crash, or they may be shown a receipt at PayPal and need to click a button to return, and so just close the window.

If you need reliable notifications of payment completion, your options are:

1. Implement a separate asynchronous service, such as Webhooks or IPN.
2. Switch to an API-based integration that is notified synchronously when the capture is successful, such as a server-side integration of v2/orders with Smart Payment Buttons (front-end code: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server ). This way, the capture happens on your server, and you have an immediate API notification of success/failure